# How to properly get if a number is between two given numbers in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Given this rule to follow:

[image]

And I have some value to check from this:

[image]

Where cell **AA727** is a result of some calculations which I already formatted into a number (this includes all operands involved). In cell **O727**, I have this formula: `=IF(AND(AA727>=A14;AA727<=B14);"True";"False")`. I am wondering why it gives me **False**, when it is supposed to be **True**? But if I manually entered  **1.00** into cell **AA727** it gives me **True**.

Any help or suggestion is very much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use a vlookup() instead of all that if()? something like =vlookup(aa727,A13:C23,3,1) Not tested though...

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you very much. It works, at least, in my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so the question has an answer:

I would suggest something like this with vlookup():

```
=vlookup(aa727,A13:C23,3,1)
```

Do test with all the values and adjust the numbers as needed.

Answer (score 0):

try like this casting the references:

=IF(AND(num(AA727)>=num(A14);num(AA727)<=num(B14));"True";"False")